# Have these two Doctor Who characters ever met before?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Magician's Apprentice*, the first episode of the new Series 9 of *Doctor Who*, we encounter both

> Missy (the Master)

and

> Davros, creator of the Daleks.

Have these two characters ever appeared together in any *Doctor Who* episode (old or new) before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they've never appeared together on-screen before.

The first character mentioned in the question has appeared in the following episodes:

- *Terror of the Autons*
- *The Mind of Evil*
- *The Claws of Axos*
- *Colony in Space*
- *The Daemons*
- *The Sea Devils*
- *The Time Monster*
- *Frontier in Space*
- *The Deadly Assassin*
- *The Keeper of Traken*
- *Logopolis*
- *Castrovalva*
- *Time-Flight*
- *The King's Demons*
- *The Five Doctors*
- *Planet of Fire*
- *The Caves of Androzani* (as a hallucination)
- *The Mark of the Rani*
- *The Ultimate Foe*
- *Survival*
- The TV movie
- *Utopia*/*The Sound of Drums*/*Last of the Time Lords*
- *The End of Time*
- > Most episodes of series 8, as Missy
- *The Magician's Apprentice*

The second has appeared in the following:

- *Genesis of the Daleks*
- *Destiny of the Daleks*
- *Logopolis* (as a hallucination)<sup>1</sup>
- *Resurrection of the Daleks*
- *Revelation of the Daleks*
- *Rememberance of the Daleks*
- *The Stolen Earth*/*Journey's End*
- *The Magician's Apprentice*

As you can see, there are only two episodes common to both characters: *The Magician's Apprentice*, which is the episode under consideration, and *Logopolis*. However, one of our two characters only appeared as a hallucination of the Doctor, and didn't share any screen time with the other.

Although I'm not excessively familiar with the *Doctor Who* expanded universe (by which I mean the various novel series, comics, and audio productions), a quick skim of the two characters' pages on [the TARDIS Data Core (the *Doctor Who* wikia)](http://tardis.wikia.com/) indicate that they haven't met in any of them, either.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hat tip to Elliott Frisch for reminding me of this in comments

Comment: There were flashbacks to the Master and Davros in Logopolis. But they were clips, and not on screen simultaneously.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Cheers, forgot about that one

Answer (score 9):

The above answer from @JasonBaker proves that these two characters **have never been seen together** in any previous Doctor Who episode.

But in addition to this, S9E2 *The Witch's Familiar* tells us that in fact they **have never met in-universe** before either:

> DAVROS: Doctor, you must help me.
>   MISSY: Can I just say, it's been an absolute pleasure to finally meet you?
>   (She gives a little curtsey and holds out her hand, then pokes Davros in his blue eye. It hurts. Then she runs out.)
>
> <sub>-- [Chakoteya transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-2.html)</sub>

Comment: Maybe the Master has never met Davros as Missy?